# Detect only the browser close event and exclude back, forward and refresh events

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need to call a method through ajax whenever the user try to close the browser or tab. From the docs I came to know that we can achieve this through window.onbeforeunload(chrome). But this is called whenever I click on back,forward buttons or by hitting the refresh button. Is there any possible way so that I can exclude these actions and trigger it only if the browser is closed.

Below is the code snippet I am using

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (event) {
 var message = 'Important: Your will be logged out.';
 if (event) {
  $.ajax({
   ...
  });
 }
 return message;
};
```

Comment: @anquegi I referred these before and it was triggering the back, forward and refresh events too. I just need to catch only the close event Thanks :)